# sub menus vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menuitem

I have a horizontal menu made in HTML and CSS (even though the project is on .NET framework-asp and c#) that's supposed to show vertical
sub menu items when hovered over.
But that is not happening as the sub menu items
align horizontally and upset the rest of the layout, and
effecting undesired design.

this is my code so far:

> HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul class="firstLevel">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The Team</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">History</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Vision</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="firstLevel">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Cozy Couch</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Great Table</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Small Chair</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shiny Shelf</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Invisible Nothing</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul class="firstLevel">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Online</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Right Here</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Somewhere Else</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Account</a>
            <ul class="firstLevel">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> CSS:

```
#menu ul {
   clear:left;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
   text-align:center;


}
#menu ul li {
    display:block;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   right:50%;    
}
#menu li ul {
    position:relative;

}
#menu ul li a {
   display:block;
   margin:0 0 0 1px;
   padding:3px 10px;
   background:#ddd;
   color:#000;
   text-decoration:none;
   line-height:1.3em;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
   background:#369;
   color:#fff;
}

#menu ul li a.active,
#menu ul li a.active:hover {
   color:#fff;
   background:#000;
   font-weight:bold;
}

li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

}
```

This is what its showing:

Comment: Provide a fiddle link with your codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Ec98p/

try with this css

```
#menu{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:30px;

}
#menu ul {
list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;

   text-align:center;


}
#menu ul li {
    display:block;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0 2px 0 0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;

}
#menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid green;

}
#menu ul li a {
   display:block;
   margin:0 0 0 1px;
   padding:3px 10px;
   background:#ddd;
   color:#000;
   text-decoration:none;
   line-height:1.3em;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
   background:#369;
   color:#fff;
}

#menu ul li a.active,
#menu ul li a.active:hover {
   color:#fff;
   background:#000;
   font-weight:bold;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
 }
#menu ul li ul li {
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
     display:block;
    float:none;
}
#menu ul li ul li a{
    display:block;

}
```

Comment: hey @shibin thanks, but its forcing design change as it has to have a large height at '#menu{}' for all the sub menus to show. Without the height the sub menus don't show at all. Any other way to help ?

Comment: You can remove #menu height , Please show your design in jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks @Shibin, it worked. I just had to change the position property of the underlying division to 'position:inherit;' to stop the division from either being displaced or hiding the sub menu items.